# Function with no fast path and with fast proof

Tags: hash, complexity, proof-of-work

When a function is iterated and each time a previous result is used as input to the next iteration (feedback), so that there is a limited benefit from parallel computing, is there such function that:

- requires polynomial time to get the result of N iterations
- has an Nth result that can be verified in constant time to be the Nth result for a given start value

Assuming that Alice iterates the function:

Problem with Makwa: At first Bob must use and throw away p and q.

Problem with LCS35: At first Bob must construct the puzzle.

But I need a function so that Alice can choose an arbitrary number or data to begin iterating with, not something prepared by Bob. Only when Alice has done N iterations Bob will join and verify.

Comment: I've read http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9327/parallel-resistant-proof-of-work-scheme but it was answered before Makwa was created and I'd like to know more about Makwa in this regard and whether my question is asking for the impossible.

Comment: There was some discussion concernig this on the PHC list some time ago. [This](http://www.hiero.lu/doc/H1_dmitry-khovratovich-proof-of-work.pdf) and [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/430.pdf) was one of their outcomes. BTW: Makwa isn't suitable (as you found out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following paragraph applies even if the honest prover does not use iteration.

Strictly speaking, only a constant-size part of the input can be read from in

constant time, so one could always find a suitable result in constant time.

For a *deterministic* verifier that makes at most k [probes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell-probe_model) to an alleged result

consisting of M [w-bit words](http://opendatastructures.org/versions/edition-0.1e/ods-cpp/1_3_Model_Computation.html), one can find a suitable result with ​ 2<sup>$\hspace{.02 in}$w$\hspace{.02 in}\cdot$k</sup> ​ *parallel*

simulations of the verifier, each of which uses only ​ $(\hspace{.02 in}2\hspace{-0.05 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.04 in}k)\hspace{-0.04 in}+\hspace{.02 in}$[O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)(1) ​ words of overhead.

If instead the verifier is probabilistic, then either ​ [$\binom{M}{\hspace{.02 in}k\cdot \hspace{.02 in}(1+\hspace{.03 in}\Omega(1))\hspace{-0.03 in}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)$\cdot$2<sup>$\hspace{.02 in}$w$\hspace{.02 in}\cdot$k$\cdot$(1+$\hspace{.03 in}$[Ω](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Big_Omega_notation)(1))</sup> ​ parallel

simulations will be enough, or the adversary can very-efficiently go from an actual result

to one that makes the verifier's acceptance probability be between Ω(1) and 1-$\hspace{.02 in}$Ω(1).

However, it may well be possible to achieve what you're asking about with a probabilistic

[word RAM](http://opendatastructures.org/versions/edition-0.1e/ods-cpp/1_3_Model_Computation.html) verifier, by simply accepting that "the adversary ... be between ... ."

[PCPs of proximity with highly-efficient verifiers](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/research/polylogPCP.pdf) do something that is somewhat similar.